# One Solution To A Set Of 3 Linear Equations With 3 Variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the geometry of that solution set.
If there is one solution thats mean that there is only one place where those 3, 3 Dimensions intersect, that mean that 2 of them are touching the other one, and each other with their corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More like three planes oriented in different directions all touch each other at one point. The first two planes form a line of intersection, and the final plane intersects with that line at one point.